# CSS Grid - move it behind the menu bar

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Problem: i am building a webpage and learning to use grids with [CSS](https://elementtutorials.com/css/css-tutorial.html).
But i am running into a problem with it, as the dropdown menu i have at the top of the page, goes BEHIND the grid-items.

i've tried using the z-index: -1; and z-index:1; on just about every block there is regarding both the menu and the grid.
But so far have been unsuccesfull.

So here i am.

How do i do this??

A fiddle to see my "problem" 
Here is a [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Dustmuz/2syLcp85/8/) of the problem.

it might just be me which is missing something obvious, but i am still learning :D

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 350px 350px 350px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.grid-item {
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid rgb(13, 7, 95);
  margin: 5px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.menu-bar {
  border-radius: 25px;
  height: -webkit-fit-content;
  height: -moz-fit-content;
  height: fit-content;
  display: inline-flex;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
  backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 10px;
  margin: 50px 0 0 0;
}

.menu-bar li {
  list-style: none;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  margin: 0 8px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.menu-bar li::before {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  transition: 0.2s;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

.menu-bar li:hover {
  color: black;
}

.menu-bar li:hover::before {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #e8edec, #d2d1d3);
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 20px 0px black;
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

li {
  float: center;
}

li a,
.dropbtn {
  display: inline-block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: red;
}

li.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}


.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);

}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu-bar">
  <li class="dropdown">
    <p>Test 1</p>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <p> test 1 </p>
      <p> test 2 </p>
      <p> test 3 </p>
      <p> test 4 </p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <p>Test 2</p>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <p> test 1 </p>
      <p> test 2 </p>
      <p> test 3 </p>
      <p> test 4 </p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <p>Test 3</p>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <p> test 1 </p>
      <p> test 2 </p>
      <p> test 3 </p>
      <p> test 4 </p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <p>Test 4 </p>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <p>Test 5 </p>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <p> test 1 </p>
      <p> test 2 </p>
      <p> test 3 </p>
      <p> test 4 </p>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p> hello world </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are positioning the grid items but you are not positioning their parent, so the system 'hunts back up' for an ancestor with position (or uses body if all else fails) and positions the item relative to that. You can add a position to the parent (or remove the position on the items).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `position: relative` from `.grid-item`:

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 350px 350px 350px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.grid-item {
  border: 2px solid rgb(13, 7, 95);
  margin: 5px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.menu-bar {
  border-radius: 25px;
  height: -webkit-fit-content;
  height: -moz-fit-content;
  height: fit-content;
  display: inline-flex;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
  backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 10px;
  margin: 50px 0 0 0;
}

.menu-bar li {
  list-style: none;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  margin: 0 8px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.menu-bar li::before {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  transition: 0.2s;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

.menu-bar li:hover {
  color: black;
}

.menu-bar li:hover::before {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #e8edec, #d2d1d3);
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 20px 0px black;
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

li {
  float: center;
}

li a,
.dropbtn {
  display: inline-block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: red;
}

li.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}


.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);

}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu-bar">
  <li class="dropdown">
    <p>Test 1</p>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <p> test 1 </p>
      <p> test 2 </p>
      <p> test 3 </p>
      <p> test 4 </p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <p>Test 2</p>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <p> test 1 </p>
      <p> test 2 </p>
      <p> test 3 </p>
      <p> test 4 </p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <p>Test 3</p>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <p> test 1 </p>
      <p> test 2 </p>
      <p> test 3 </p>
      <p> test 4 </p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <p>Test 4 </p>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <p>Test 5 </p>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <p> test 1 </p>
      <p> test 2 </p>
      <p> test 3 </p>
      <p> test 4 </p>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p> hello world </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @ThomasJunker
 but the item are still behind the box

Comment: @Saleh Not for me, in which browser are you observing that?

Comment: in Google Chrome

Comment: Not in my Chrome (97.0.4692.99, MacOS, arm64 build).

Comment: I mean the items of the navbar (test 1, test 2, ...) are still behind the li::before element

Comment: the problem was that rectangle?

Comment: For me it worked in both Chrome and firefox

Answer (score 0):

you have to add '**z-index: -1;**' to '**.dropdown::before**'
and remove position: relative from .grid-item:

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 350px 350px 350px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.grid-item {
  border: 2px solid rgb(13, 7, 95);
  margin: 5px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.menu-bar {
  border-radius: 25px;
  height: -webkit-fit-content;
  height: -moz-fit-content;
  height: fit-content;
  display: inline-flex;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
  backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 10px;
  margin: 50px 0 0 0;
}

.menu-bar li {
  list-style: none;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  margin: 0 8px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.menu-bar li::before {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  transition: 0.2s;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

.menu-bar li:hover {
  color: black;
}

.menu-bar li:hover::before {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #e8edec, #d2d1d3);
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 20px 0px black;
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

li {
  float: center;
}

li a,
.dropbtn {
  display: inline-block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: red;
}

li.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}


.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);

}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
  z-index: 1;
}
.dropdown::before {
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu-bar">
  <li class="dropdown">
    <p>Test 1</p>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <p> test 1 </p>
      <p> test 2 </p>
      <p> test 3 </p>
      <p> test 4 </p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <p>Test 2</p>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <p> test 1 </p>
      <p> test 2 </p>
      <p> test 3 </p>
      <p> test 4 </p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <p>Test 3</p>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <p> test 1 </p>
      <p> test 2 </p>
      <p> test 3 </p>
      <p> test 4 </p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <p>Test 4 </p>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <p>Test 5 </p>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <p> test 1 </p>
      <p> test 2 </p>
      <p> test 3 </p>
      <p> test 4 </p>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p> hello world </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I hope this solution helps

Comment: You also removed `position: relative` from `.grid-item` (which alone is sufficient here).